# Mac OS X Individual Application Volume Levels

Tags: macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Per application volume settings: possible on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/150304/per-application-volume-settings-possible-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard)

So, coming from Windows 7, I can define individual application volume levels.  Is this possible on Mac OSX?

Comment: Am I a bad person for wanting to make an "It just works" joke?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no (at least, not without a fair amount of hacking). Some applications allow you to route their sound to sound devices other than the one selected in System Preferences, though. For instance, Skype allows you to route sound through a headset connected via Bluetooth or an iMic, while the system sound is routed to the built-in speakers, allowing you to turn the person you're talking to up and down without getting deafened every time you get an e-mail. Such applications usually have their own volume settings, too, making this fairly moot - I doubt you'd be asking if the application you're interested in had a volume control.